# How do you load a prototype cell from a storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, ocunit, sentestingkit

Is there a way to load a prototype cell, along with any IBOutlet connections as defined within a storyboard?

**Update**

I want to unit test the cell (a UICollectionViewCell for that mater), hence would like to load it outside of a UIViewController context.

Effectively, in the same way that you can load a custom view from a nib, specifying its file's owner and have its IBOutlet(s) set.

Comment: you should connect the IBOutlets to the interface of a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Edit: As far as I know, it's not possible to use prototype UITableViewCells from a Storyboard anywhere other than the ViewController you created it in.

I haven't  tried this with unit tests yet but you can easily put your custom `UITableViewCell` into a separate nib.

For using it in your view controllers you need to **register the cell** with your tableViews.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ABCNameOfYourNibCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
```

Then use the cell like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCustomCell";

ABCNameOfYourNibCell *cell = 
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

For your **testing purposes** you should be able to go with:

```
ABCNameOfYourNibCell *testCell = 
[[ABCNameOfYourNibCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

If you need to test reuse-behaviour, you should set a reuseIdentifier here and call `prepareForReuse` on the cell.

Comment: I'll take it that the answer is 'NO' and the only way is to declare it to a standalone nib, right?

Answer (score 10):

Normally you crete an `UITableViewController` or a `UITableView`. Than you should also create a `UITableViewCell` class. After creating the `UITableViewCell` class, go to the `UIStoryboard, select the cell :

[image]

Then set the `UITableViewCell` class inside the `Identity Inspector`:

[image]

Now add elements to the `UITableViewCell` and connect them with your class

[image]

Now add the `CellIdentifier` inside the `Attributes Inspector`:

[image]

No got to your `UITableViewController` or the `UIViewController` where you have the `UITableViewDelegate` methods and call your cell like this (don't forget to `#import` the `UITableViewCell` class at the top of your `ViewController`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Cell at Row %ld", 
                         (long)indexPath.row]];      
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Do you mean if the prototype cell is connected as an IBOutlet to the view controller?

Comment: Sorry for the last question, thought you want to load the cell from another `UIViewController`, this should be what your looking for

Comment: Irrelevant answer as question is how to load prototype cell created in storyboard in the separate test class.