# How can i set an imageview over 2 table view cells

Tags: uitableview, imageview, avatar

I'm trying to construct a register page similar to the one used by instagram or foursquare , the problem is they have a special mechanism in a table view where you can set your avatar , like so :

[image]

It seems like an imageview was added above 2 tableview cells , obviously the insets are modified so the line doesn't touch it , but i can't seem to place the image or modifiy the tableview cell width .

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: What XML ? This is a native app, also : ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a single cell with 3 `UIImageViews`, 2 `UITextFields`, `UIButton` and a dividing line being another subview (perhaps thin `UIView`). You can easily achieve this with a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

**Update:** review this question for steps how to achieve it in storyboard: [How do you load a prototype cell from a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257105/how-do-you-load-a-prototype-cell-from-a-storyboard/22258311#22258311) You would need IBOutlets for `UITextFields` and IBAction for `UIButton`.

Comment: I actually use tags for static cells if i'm not drawing anything . But your solution to my problem works fine , using 1 cell with multiple fields is the simplest and easiest way to do it . Thanks !