# Programmatically create instance of UICollectionViewCell from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I have designed a collection view + custom cell as part of a view controller in Interface Builder. I would like to create an instance of that custom cell programmatically, just so I can use it for measuring it's dynamic size. How do I create an instance of an object from a storyboard based on it's name or it's reuse identifier (not by dequeueing a reusable cell). It it was a different xib, it would have been easier, but since it's all part of one storyboard I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Thank you!

Comment: use the collectionview name

Comment: @KishoreKumar could you please elaborate thanks :)

Comment: Seems like it is not possible based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257105/how-do-you-load-a-prototype-cell-from-a-storyboard

Comment: Why not dequeue a cell?  Another option is to override  'sizeForItemAtIndexPath', but that's a flow layout delegate method and almost presupposes that you already know what size the cell should be.

Comment: Because when you call dequeue, it's for a specific row/section. I wanted to keep that object for "measurement" purposes.

Comment: About a year later, I can say that probably calling dequeue was the right thing to do :-)