# Can I replace all xib with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, xib

I wonder if there is any way to replace all xib with storyboard. I am using a tableview which uses a custom cell. Usually all online resources and tutorials guide to make a xib and then load from delegate on a custom cell class. I dont want to use any xib in my project. How can I transfer those cell xib to storyboard and instantiate from there.

Comment: No way I know of to *automate* the process, but designing tableview cells in Storyboards is not much different at all from designing them as separate xibs. Just do a search for `uitableviewcell prototype storyboard` and you'll find hundreds / thousands of example and tutorials.

Comment: could you plz share any tutorial where custom cell without xib is implemented. thanks.

Comment: Did you search for examples? Here is a *video* tutorial (may be easier for you to follow): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59D_whJxKf0

Comment: thanks a lot. is there anything in xib which cant be replaced with storyboard?

Comment: Not that i know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and study I found that there is no such functionality in xib which cannot be replaced with storyboard. Thanks to @DonMag for comments and clue.

The only issue I was facing is to design uitableview cell, but prototype cell design can be used easily from storyboard. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22257583/1084174) are some example how to use it.